# Asp MVC 5 dropdown list from different model

Tags: asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor

I am building a project in asp.net with mvc 5 using entity framework 6.1.0. I have models containing some values in number format, and 1 model containing number values, domains and description (meaning) of that values.

How can I create dropdown list containing description of that value in a model.

I will show you this in an sql query, and I can post any code if you need.

```
select
value, 
description 
from
table t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.number_value = t1.value
where
t1.domain = 'COLORS';
```

This query for example will give me all descriptions from COLORS domain. Something like this:

```
Value  Description  Domain
1      Yellow       COLORS
2      Blue         COLORS
3      Red          COLORS
```

Lets say I want to have a record of 1 car like this:

```
name  model  year  color
Opel  Astra  2014   2
```

In my model editing view I want to show dropdown list with all COLORS values, but I only want to store selected one.

Later on I want to show dropdown list again but with selected option.

Can you help me please?

Model:

```
    public partial class korisnik_detalji
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int korisnik_id { get; set; }
        public string ime { get; set; }
        public string prezime { get; set; }
        public string adresa { get; set; }
        public string grad { get; set; }
        public string drzava { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> mj_tezine { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> mj_tekucine { get; set; }
        public string slika { get; set; }

        public virtual korisnik korisnik { get; set; }
    }
//This is model with values and descriptions

    public partial class mapiranja
    {
        public int vrijednost { get; set; }
        public string opis { get; set; }
        public string domena { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model eVinogradarstvo.Models.korisnik_detalji
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detalji";
}
<div id="main_middle">
    <div id="detalji">
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
        <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.korisnik.UserName)</h2>
        <div class="profil">
            <div class="slika">
            @if (Model.slika != null)
            { 
                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.slika)" />
            }
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Promijeni sliku", null)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Promijeni lozinku", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Promijeni podatke", "Edit", new { id = Model.id })
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="podaci">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>Ime</label>
                  @if (Model.ime != null)
                  {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ime)
                  }
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Prezime</label>
                @if (Model.prezime != null)
                { 
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.prezime)
                }

                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Adresa</label>
                 @if (Model.adresa != null)
                 { 
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.adresa)
                 }
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Grad</label>
                @if (Model.grad != null)
                { 
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.grad)
                }
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Država</label>
                @if (Model.drzava != null)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.drzava)
                }
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Mjerna jedinica težine</label>
                @if (Model.mj_tezine != null)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.mj_tezine)
                }
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Mjerna jedinica tekućine</label>
                @if (Model.mj_tekucine != null)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.mj_tekucine)
                }
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
}else
{
        <p style="font-size:16px">Molimo da se @Html.ActionLink("prijavite", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" }) ili @Html.ActionLink("registrirate", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</p>
}
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I am displaying number values of mj_tezine and mj_tekucine, but I want to  get description of these values. Descriptions are in model mapiranja.opis. Number value is in mapiranja.vrijednost

Comment: some code would help, but have you tried sending both models to your view in one combined view model?

Comment: I didn't post code because its only 2 models and 1 view. Here it is now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, create a ViewModel

**View Model**

```
public class DetaljiViewModel {
    public korisnik_detalji kd { get; set; }
    public mapiranja m { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownItems { get; set; }
}
```

Second Change your View to use the ViewModel (i am going to give a very short view to show how)

```
@model eVinogradarstvo.Models.DetaljiViewModel 
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.kd.prezime)</h2>
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.m.opis )</h2>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.m.[PropertyToSaveTheSelectedValue], Model.DropDownItems )
```

Please change [PropertyToSaveTheSelectedValue] to whatever property you actually expect the selected value to be stored in

Comment: Ok, thank you for your solution, I will try it and let you know if this did the trick.

Comment: It's working with some changes, great man, thank you very very much!